# Instagram images have stopped pulling through

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I've been using some Javascript to pull in my Instagram feed to my website but recently it's completely stopped pulling through, has something changed recently with Instagram that might be causing this?

I did a Google search to see if there was a change somewhere but couldn't seem to find anything

Here's the code I'm using

```
$(function() {
var cmdURL, embedImage, onPhotoLoaded, param, tag_name, userid,
param = {
access_token: '3794301.f59def8.e08bcd8b10614074882b2d1b787e2b6f', // feel free to change it with your own access token
count: 10 // the total number of images
},
tag = 'Gezzamondoportfolio', // your user id. you can find this one out by looking into one of your pictures uri
tag_name = '#photowall',
cmdURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tag + '/media/recent?callback=?';

 embedImage = function(photo) {
var a, img;
img = $('<img/>').attr({
  //'src': photo.images.thumbnail.url,
  //'width': photo.images.thumbnail.width,
  //'height': photo.images.thumbnail.height
  'src': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
  'width': photo.images.standard_resolution.width,
  'height': photo.images.standard_resolution.height
});
a = $('<a />').attr({
  'href': photo.images.standard_resolution.url,
  'target': '_blank',
  'class': 'pull-left'
}).append(img).appendTo(tag_name);
};

onPhotoLoaded = function(data) {
var photo, _i, _len, _ref, _results;
if (data.meta.code === 200 && data.data) {
  _ref = data.data;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    photo = _ref[_i];
    _results.push(embedImage(photo));
  }
  return _results;
}
};
return $.getJSON(cmdURL, param, onPhotoLoaded);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem earlier this day (with PHP, not jQuery / JSON).
I found that, apparently, Instagram feed has changed. To get images source, I found :

```
'src': photo.images.standard_resolution
```

Width and height are no longer supplied.

Comment: Now, Instagram feed is back to previous structure.

Comment: I'm still unable to pull my feen into the webpage. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you went over your requests per hour limit.  I accessed this link and got the following error: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/Gezzamondoportfolio/media/recent?callback=?&access_token=3794301.f59def8.e08bcd8b10614074882b2d1b787e2b6f

```
{"code": 420, "error_type": "OAuthRateLimitException", "error_message": "You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 345 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum request limit is set at 30 requests per hour."}
```

Comment: ive not access the feed at all so how would I have exceed the requests per hour? can you see any other issue that might be causing this to have suddenly stopped

Comment: Where did you get this access token?  It this yours, or did you get it somewhere else?

Comment: think i might have got it somewhere else, where would i get my own access token?

Comment: If you got this from anywhere else on the web I'm not surprised it's over any limits as others probably did the same.  To get one for yourself it looks like you need to go to the developer page and set up an account: http://instagram.com/developer

Comment: I've registered a new client and then I used this URL

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

to replace the clients ID and redirect Url with what i was assigned

I then was redirected to a page where it displayed a code in the Url but from there I don't have a clue where id then get my access token.